# Python - How to move output text to the left / up?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from __future__ import print_function
import textwrap
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def bbb_spider(max_pages):
    bus_cat = raw_input('Enter a business category: ')
    pages = 1
    while pages <= max_pages:
        url = 'http://www.bbb.org/search/?type=category&input=' +     str(bus_cat) + '&page=' + str(pages)
        sauce_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = sauce_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.select("table.search-results-table tr h4 a"):
            href = link.get('href')
            bbb_profiles(href)
        pages += 1

def bbb_profiles(profile_urls):
    sauce_code = requests.get(profile_urls)
    plain_text = sauce_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    for business_name in soup.findAll("h1", {"class": "business-title"}):
        print(business_name.string)
    for business_phone in soup.findAll("span", {"class": "business-phone"}):
        print(business_phone.string)
    for business_address in soup.select("div.business-detail-text p span.nobr"):
        print(business_address.string, end=" ")

sort_pages = input('How many pages to sort through?: ')
bbb_spider(sort_pages)
```

So I have some output that looks like this:

```
Phone
                    Address      Name of Business
```

What I would like to have is:

```
 Name of Business 
 Phone
 Address
```

Basically what's happening here is that throughout my foreach loop, for the next block of items arranged how i'd like (name, phone, address), the name is on the same line as the previous address's block. So what I'm trying to do is bring the name down and to the left, then address to the left, and then the phone will be fine as is.

Comment: check the raw strings. they may contain the spaces you're seeing, then you need to `trim` them.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Ahh. strip() function yes?

Comment: @n0de Yes. Before throwing it in, _first check if this is the issue._

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev  hmm. .get_text(strip=True) seemed to work. Thank you for your help guys :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.get_text(strip=True)`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) instead of `.string`:

```
print(business_name.get_text(strip=True))
```